# Why cannot I get MaldiveIslands EntityClass?

Tags: entity

[image]
Why cannot I get MaldiveIslands EntityClass?

Answer (score 1):

If you look in `EntityValue[EntityList@Entity["Island"]]`, you will see, in particular, `Entity["Island", "WestFalkland"]` and `Entity["Island", "EastFalkland"]`.